# Can we create individual admin section for individual store

Tags: magento-1.7, admin, magento-enterprise, multistore

I have created multiple store like store1,store2 in magento.Can we Create individual admin section for each store, so that store1 can operate(add product,view sales record) only with own store admin section?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot create an individual admin for each store, but you can create admin roles separated by store. Magento EE allows you this. Just go to `System->Permissions->Roles`. Create a role with access only to store1, after that from `System->Permissions->Users` create an admin with the role you created in the previous step, login with his credentials and see what you have access to.